# How to remove black colored seam on my separated floor mesh? AFRAME/THREEJS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I have a big .glb file that I import in **AFrame**. This .glb file has **baked textures** for my model and the floor has been separated into multiple mesh parts for better resolution.

On the parts that the **floor has been separated**, those **black seams appear** and they disappear only when the camera gets closer.

For my renderer settings:
`renderer='colorManagement: true; antialias: true; alpha: false;'`

Any idea what this is and how to remove it?
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the black edges disappear as the camera gets closer, then it's almost certainly a [mipmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) issue. Can you share what the floor texture image looks like? I recommend using a tileable texture that can repeat endlessly, instead of one with custom edges.

Answer (score 0):

If they disappear when you get close, they may be related to the `z-buffer`, take a look at this example: [webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer.html).

Anyways if it's not, you should also try adding `THREE.DoubleSide` on the `side` property of your glb model like this:

```js
model.traverse((o) => {
  if (o.isMesh) o.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
});
```

If nothing of this works,I would think about a modelling issue. Anyways try adding a minimal working example like this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, @alon but I don't think either one of those suggestions address the problem. There is no z-fighting in the geometry, and the side of the faces are displaying correctly.